# Rename files sequentially

Tags: vb.net

with reference to [Renaming all files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930272/renaming-all-files-in-a-folder)

on running the below code, get type def errors:
Type 'DirectoryInfo' is not defined
Type 'FileInfo' is not defined

how to resolve these errors. Please suggest.

```
Dim sourcePath As String = "E:\testrenamerbackup\vbdotnet"
Dim searchPattern As String = "*.doc"
Dim curDir As New DirectoryInfo(sourcePath)
Dim i As Integer = 0
For Each fi As FileInfo In curDir.GetFiles(searchPattern).OrderBy(Function(num) num.CreationTime)
    File.Move(fi.FullName, Path.Combine(fi.Directory.FullName, "docFile_" & i & ".doc"))
i += 1
Next
```

Comment: Hold your mouse over them, click the arrow,  the VB IDE will offer to fix it for you.  If it cant find those, it should also complain about `Path`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Import System.IO` on top of your vb.net class file, for example

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
     ' your code...
    End Sub
End Class
```

System.IO Namespace contains types that allow reading and writing to files and data streams, and types that provide basic file and directory support including `DirectoryInfo`, `FileInfo`. by adding `Import System.IO` you can use those types and methods in the namespace.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. needless to say i am a newbee